# Retina iconLink with Google Drive API

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm an getting a list of files in a folder. The response contains a  `iconLink` for every file returned. This icon is 16x16 pixels.

Does anyone know a way to retrieve a retina image? Or another way to retrieve a bigger icon image?

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files

**top**: Google Drive UI

**bottom**: Google Drive API integration

[image: Example]

Comment: What have you done so far? In every file returned, have you tried to re-size the icon image in a bigger icon?

Comment: The icon url returned leads to a 16x16 pixel image. (eg https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_12_pdf_list.png). I tried to add @2x to see if thats available, but no luck so far

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope not yet ;-( Maybe we will get an answer with a bounty on it

Answer (score 3):

The good news is although not officailly documented driver does have 2x resolution icons. The bad news is they have inconsistent file names; for example the icon you linked in the comments has a 32px version availabel here: [ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_3_pdf_x32.png](http://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_3_pdf_x32.png)

Now here is my soltion, it's not perfect but it will do the job for a while:

```
function getIcons($file_type)
{ 
    $icons = [
        'pdf' => [
            'icon' => 'icon_12_pdf_list.png',
            'retina' => 'icon_3_pdf_x32.png'
         ],
        'document' => [
            'icon' => 'icon_1_document_x16.png',
            'retina' => 'icon_1_document_x32.png'
        ],
        'image' => [
            'icon' => 'con_1_image_x16.png',
            'retina' => 'icon_1_image_x32.png'
        ],
        'word' => [
            'icon' => 'icon_1_word_x16.png',
            'retina' => 'icon_1_word_x32.png'
        ],
        'text' => [
            'icon' => 'icon_1_text_x16.png',
            'retina' => 'icon_1_text_x32.png'
        ],
        'spreadsheet' => [
            'icon' => 'icon_1_spreadsheet_x16.png',
            'retina' => 'icon_1_spreadsheet_x32.png'
        ],
        'form' => [
            'icon' => 'icon_2_form_x16.png',
            'retina' => 'icon_2_form_x32.png'
        ],
        'audio' => [
            'icon' => 'icon_1_audio_x16.png',
            'retina' => 'icon_1_audio_x32.png'
        ]
    ];

    return isset($icons[$file_type]) ? $icons[$file_type] : $icons['text'];
}
```

The reasion I say it will work for a while is that I'm asuming the `_3_` in pdf icon file name for instance is the version number. So if Google updates it's icons again in the future this solution may brake.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using drive rest api and what i observed was that `iconLink` attribute had a definite pattern.
`"https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/" + size + mimetype`
By default size is 16. So, before adding your icon to Image, use this:

```
    String iconLink = (String) jsonObject.get("iconLink");
    iconLink=iconLink.replace("16","128");
```

check out these both links:
https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/128/type/application/pdf
https://drive-thirdparty.googleusercontent.com/16/type/application/pdf

Answer (score 0):

Looks like images with x128 also added/present for various versions:

[Ver. 1](http://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_1_pdf_x128.png)

[Ver. 2](http://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_2_pdf_x128.png)

[Ver. 3](http://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/mediatype/icon_3_pdf_x128.png)

Better to replace the     `x16` from the fetched     `iconLink` and replace it with     `x128`.